# Is it possible to create a tcp client with electron

Tags: electron

Is it possible to create a tcp client with electron?
Or can we access the chrome socket api with does that?

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Node `net` API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/net.html) in Electron to implement a TCP client.

Try this sample code (don't forget to change IP address) with a little socket server as SocketTest java application for example ([HERE](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/)).

At the connection, you should see a "World!" string on server side. Try to send this message from server:

```json
{
    "nom":"Xplorer",
    "prenom":"Yann"
}
```

And you should see Hello Yann! in your electron console.

```js
'use strict';

const electron = require('electron');

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const net = require('net');

const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

let mainWindow;
var socketClient

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600,backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF', frame:false})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname+'/html/', 'main.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })

  /* Instance socket on create window */
  console.log('Try to connect');
  socketClient = net.connect({host:'192.16.122.3', port:9042},  () => {
    // 'connect' listener
    console.log('connected to server!');
    socketClient.write('world!\r\n');
  });

  socketClient.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    var person = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log('Hello '+person.prenom+"!");

  });
  socketClient.on('end', () => {
    console.log('disconnected from server');
  });

  //mainWindow.openDevTools();
}
app.on('before-quit',function(){
  socketClient.end();
})
```

see you.

Comment: Awesome; it is even asynchroneous! - For simple tests without json, `netcat -l -p 9024` is enough for launching a server and communicating with the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Node `net` API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/net.html) in Electron to implement a TCP client.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to just test if the chrome API is present. If not I use the node API. So that I have the same code base for my Chrome App and my Electron App.
The 2 APIs are slightly different so I post here how to do it.

```
  let client = null; // node socket
  let socketId; // chrome API socket id

  function toBuffer(ab) {
    return new Buffer(new Uint8Array(ab));
  }

  function toArrayBuffer(buf) {
    return new Uint8Array(buf).buffer;
  }

  function initConnToServer (ip, port) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(typeof chrome !== 'undefined') {
        chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, r => {
          socketId = r.socketId;
          chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(r.socketId, ip, port, code => resolve(code));
        });
      } else {
        client = new net.Socket(); // return a Node socket
        client.connect(port, ip);
        client.on('connect', () => resolve());
      }
    });
  };

  function sendToServer_simple (data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(typeof chrome !== 'undefined') {
        chrome.sockets.tcp.send(socketId, data, r => {});
        chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(receiveInfo => resolve(receiveInfo.data));
      } else {
        client.write(toBuffer(data));
        client.on('data', data => resolve(toArrayBuffer(data)));
      }
    });
  };
```